# What are "shrss" / "shswp" in atop?

Tags: memory, atop

> MEM - Memory occupation.
>
> This  line  contains the total amount of physical memory (`tot`), [...] the resident size  of  shared  memory  including  tmpfs
>               (`shmem`), the resident size of shared memory (`shrss`) the amount of shared memory that is currently swapped (`shswp`) [...]

The description of `shrss` / `shswp` is too vague for me.   What does it actually cover?

`MEM | tot     7.7G  | free    3.6G |  cache   2.1G |  dirty   0.3M | buff  258.1M  | slab  306.4M |  slrec 182.7M | shmem 257.5M  | shrss  12.7M |  shswp   0.0M |  vmbal   0.0M |               | hptot   0.0M |  hpuse   0.0M |`

---

```
$ rpm -q atop
atop-2.4.0-1.fc30.x86_64
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"System V shared memory" only.  This is obsolescent.

The most common use is [for X Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIT-SHM).  Although some X programs [could use POSIX shared memory instead](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/xorg/2017-January/058563.html).

---

`shrss` and `shswp` are obtained (in units of pages) by the following code in `atop/photosyst.c`:

```
/*
** get information about the shared memory statistics
*/
if ( shmctl(0, SHM_INFO, (struct shmid_ds *)&shminfo) != -1)
{
    si->mem.shmrss = shminfo.shm_rss;
    si->mem.shmswp = shminfo.shm_swp;
}
```

[man shmctl](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/shmctl.2.html) says:

> shmctl - System V shared memory control